# Github Pages Site Not Building

Tags: html, css, github-pages, astrojs, github-pages-deploy-action

I get this error when I try to deploy a github pages website. I am new to deploying websites with it, so I do not know what to do to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated!

```
BaseLayout.astro
    ---
    import '~/assets/styles/base.css';
    import MetaTags from '~/components/core/MetaTags.astro';
    import BasicScripts from '~/components/core/BasicScripts.astro';
    
    const {meta = {}} = Astro.props;
    ---
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" class="motion-safe:scroll-smooth 2xl:text-[20px]">
        <head>
            <MetaTags {...meta}/>
        </head>
        <body class="antialiased text-gray-900 dark:text-slate-300 tracking-tight bg-white dark:bg-slate-950">
            <slot/>
            <BasicScripts/>
            <style is:global>
                img {
                    content-visibility: auto;
                }
            </style>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Error

```
ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Invalid YAML front matter in /github/workspace/source/layouts/BaseLayout.astro
```

Comment: This looks like a configuration issue, check out https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/deploy/github/